# Need formal mathematical definition of this concept

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, algorithms

Assume we have a function $y=f(x)$ that is $\textit{C}^\infty$ and the function has a number of local maximums. Assume there are $k$ such maximums $\{m_1, m_2, m_3, \ldots , m_k\}$ where $f'(m_i)=0$.

If I performed a gradient ascent algorithm for any point $x$ where $f(x)$ is defined, it would get to one of these local maximums $m_i$. In this way, every point $x$ where $f(x)$ is defined, it *belongs* to a certain local maximum (via gradient ascent).

Is there a formal mathematical treatment of this concept that I just described? I have reduced it to two-dimensions, but I am looking to apply it to three dimensional surfaces.

Comment: It would highly depend on the gradient ascent algorithm parameters, namely, the steps.

Comment: You make a good point. Missing a local minima due to large step size, is it possible to avoid these situations and converge always to the local minima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the context of Morse theory these are known as the *(un)stable manifolds* of the critical points $m_i$.

If $\phi(x,t)$ is the gradient flow of $f$ (or more generally any flow):

$$ \phi(x,0) = x \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(x,t) = \nabla f(\phi(x,t))$$
then the stable and unstable manifolds at a critical point $p$ of $f$ are defined by

$$ W^s_p = \{ x | \lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(x,t) = p\}\;\text{ and }\;
 W^u_p = \{ x | \lim_{t \to -\infty} \phi(x,t) = p\}$$ respectively.

Comment: Seems like this is what I need. Can you slightly elaborate Stable and unstable manifold in the context of those points that have an affinity towards a critical point? Are these in the stable manifold? Then what are the unstables?

Comment: @dr_rk: The stable manifold of a critical point $p$ is the set of points that will converge to $p$. The unstable manifold is the same thing with  reversed time, i.e.  gradient ascent swapped for descent.

Comment: Thanks! Others who stumble upon this question might find this paper which describes the application of Morse theory to digital images, why is where my question arises from: Delgado-Friedrichs, O, "Skeletonization and partitioning of digital images using discrete Morse theory" in IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a zone of attraction or neighborhood of an optimum.

If you think of the gradient search as a dynamic process then these zones are limit sets.

Comment: "Basin of attraction" is another word for it too.